# How to import XML file in to Dynamics AX 2012?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am wondering which is the best way to import XML file like (purchase orders) into Dynamics AX?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few examples available via searching the web...

[Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=XML) suggests two libraries:

- [XMLDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa611587%28v=ax.50%29.aspx), [code example](http://axzaptech.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/read-xml-file-in-ax/)
- [SAXReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa882719%28v=ax.10%29.aspx), which may be better for parsing large XML files

Answer (score 1):

Here are good examples of how to

- [Read XML](http://daxonline.org/1459-read-xml-in-ax.html)
- [Create XML](http://daxonline.org/1460-create-xml-in-ax.html)

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the size of the XML, we have seen large file sizes that caused the XMLDocument class to consume too many memory because it loads the XML in memory.

You could also use the XMLTextReader if you need performance and you don't need schema validation.
If you do need schema validation, you would have to stick to XMLDocument. (check out this article

Check out this article on codeproject that explains XMLTextReader in full detail.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15452/The-XmlTextReader-A-Beginner-s-Guide

Also, I was wondering, do you have ownership of the application that produced the XML file? If it is something you have in your own hands, you might consider creating an AIF Custom service and call this from your other application. (But I guess you are not the owner of the application producing the XML file you want to import.)